# play! 2.1.3 scala app/views/*.jade do not get included as part of play dist

Tags: scala, playframework, pug, playframework-2.1, jade4j

My issue is that when I, run 'play dist', unzip the dist and look through the jars in lib, I can see that my app/views/*.jade files are not getting included. How do I tell play to include these jade files as part of my views??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to my Build.scala :

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory(_/"app/views")
```

this will add the contents of app/views to the root of the classpath